# typescript - how to access "root" class method

Tags: typescript

I have class inherited from other class which inherits other class, something like this:

```
class RootClass {
  call(): void;
}

class SubClass extends RootClass {
  call(): void:
}

class MyClass extends SubClass {
  call(): void {
    RootClass.call();  // how to access parent class's parent class?
  }
}
```

It seems `C++` could do something like this: `RootClass::call()`, `call` method is not static.

I know there's `super` to access base class's property&methods, is there anyway to access the `root` class method directly?

thanks!

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Not directly but manually accessing prototype  `RootClass.prototype.call.call(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the function using the `prototype` of `RootClass` and invoking it for this with `call` or `apply`

```
class MyClass extends SubClass {
    call(): void {
        RootClass.prototype.call.call(this); 
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt response, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Static and instance calls would look the following:

```
class RootClass {
   call(): void {
      console.log("RootClass")
  }

  static staticCall(): void {
    console.log("RootClass static")
  }
}

class SubClass extends RootClass {
  call(): void {
      super.call();  // run instance method of RootClass
      console.log("SubClass")
  }
}

class MyClass extends SubClass {
  call(): void {
    super.call();  // run instance method of SubClass
    RootClass.staticCall(); // run static method of RootClass
  }
}

var m = new MyClass();
m.call();
```

Comment: sure bro, thanks for rating it, I am trying to develop my reputation.